# PyInstance_NewRaw() with old and new style classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-extensions

Recently I faced a problem in a C-based python extension while trying to instantiate objects without calling its constructor -- which is a *requirement* of the extension.

The class to be used to create instances is obtained dynamically: at some point, I have an instance `x` whose class I wish to use to create other instances, so I store `x.__class__` for later use -- let this value be `klass`.

At a later point, I invoke `PyInstance_NewRaw(klass, PyDict_New())` and then, the problem arises. It seems that if `klass` is an old-style class, the result of that call is the desired new instance. However, if it is a new-style class, the result is NULL and the exception raised is:

> SystemError: ../Objects/classobject.c:521: bad argument to internal function

For the record, I'm using Python version `2.7.5`. Googling around, I observed no more than one other person looking for a solution (and it seemed to me he was doing a workaround, but didn't detailed it).

For the record #2: the instances the extension is creating are proxies for these same `x` instances -- the `x.__class__` and `x.__dict__`'s are known, so the extension is spawning new instances based on `__class__` (using the aforementioned C function) and setting the respective `__dict__` to the new instance (those `__dict__`'s have inter-process shared-memory data). Not only is conceptually problematic to call an instance's `__init__` a second time (first: it's state is already know, second: the expected behavior for ctors is that they should be called exactly once for each instance), it is also impractical, since the extension cannot figure out the arguments and their order to call the `__init__()` for each instance in the system. Also, changing the `__init__` of each class in the system whose instances may be proxies and making them aware there is a proxy mechanism they will be subjected to is conceptually problematic (they shouldn't know about it) and impractical.

So, my question is: how to perform the same behavior of `PyInstance_NewRaw` regardless of the instance's class style?

Comment: [I have to ask…](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) why is this a requirement of the extension? There must be some underlying reason you need this… and there's probably a better way to satisfy that underlying reason than this requirement.

Comment: @abarnert without going into much details, I edited the post to explain why it is a requirement.

Comment: I think there _is_ a much easier solution; I'll edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of new-style classes isn't `instance`, it's the class itself. So, the `PyInstance_*` methods aren't even meaningful for new-style classes.

In fact, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/class.html) explicitly explains this:

> Note that the class objects described here represent old-style classes, which will go away in Python 3. When creating new types for extension modules, you will want to work with type objects (section [*Type Objects*](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/type.html#typeobjects)).

So, you will have to write code that checks whether `klass` is an old-style or new-style class and does the appropriate thing for each case. An old-style class's type is `PyClass_Type`, while a new-style class's type is either `PyType_Type`, or a custom metaclass.

Meanwhile, there is no direct equivalent of `PyInstance_NewRaw` for new-style classes. Or, rather, the direct equivalent—calling its `tp_alloc` slot and then adding a dict—will give you a non-functional class. You could try to duplicate all the other appropriate work, but that's going to be tricky. Alternatively, you could use `tp_new`, but that will do the wrong thing if there's a custom `__new__` function in the class (or any of its bases). See the rejected patches from [#5180](http://bugs.python.org/issue5180) for some ideas.

But really, what you're trying to do is probably not a good idea in the first place. Maybe if you explained why this is a requirement, and what you're trying to do, there would be a better way to do it.

---

If the goal is to build objects by creating a new uninitialized instance of the class, then copying over its `_dict__` from an initialized prototype, there's a much easier solution that I think will work for you:

`__class__` is a writeable attribute. So (showing it in Python; the C API is basically the same, just a lot more verbose, and I'd probably screw up the refcounting somewhere):

```
class NewStyleDummy(object):
    pass
def make_instance(cls, instance_dict):
    if isinstance(cls, types.ClassType):
        obj = do_old_style_thing(cls)
    else:
        obj = NewStyleDummy()
        obj.__class__ = cls
    obj.__dict__ = instance_dict
    return obj
```

The new object will be an instance of `cls`—in particular, it will have the same class dictionary, including the MRO, metaclass, etc.

This won't work if `cls` has a metaclass that's required for its construction, or a custom `__new__` method, or `__slots__`… but then your design of copying over the `__dict__` doesn't make any sense in those cases anyway. I believe that in any case where anything could possibly work, this simple solution will work.

---

Calling [`cls.__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) seems like a good solution at first, but it actually isn't. Let me explain the background.

When you do this:

```
foo = Foo(1, 2)
```

(where `Foo` is a new-style class), it gets converted into something like this pseudocode:

```
foo = Foo.__new__(1, 2)
if isinstance(foo, Foo):
    foo.__init__(1, 2)
```

The problem is that, if `Foo` or one of its bases has defined a `__new__` method, it will expect to get the arguments from the constructor call, just like an `__init__` method will.

As you explained in your question, you don't know the constructor call arguments—in fact, that's the main reason you can't call the normal `__init__` method in the first place. So, you can't call `__new__` either.

The base implementation of `__new__` accepts and ignores any arguments it's given. So, if none of your classes has a `__new__` override or a `__metaclass__`, you will happen to get away with this, because of a quirk in `object.__new__` (a quirk which works differently in Python 3.x, by the way). But those are the exact same cases the previous solution can handle, and that solution works for much more obvious reason.

Put another way: The previous solution depends on nobody defining `__new__` because it never calls `__new__`. This solution depends on nobody defining `__new__` because it calls `__new__` with the wrong arguments.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your suggestions. The link to the issue you provided gave me some hints. As I understood, all objects share a default `__new__` which creates instances of a given class without calling `__init__`. I was able to have what it seems to be a workable behavior using something equivalent to `new_x = klass.__new__(klass)`.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva: Well, you have to pass the constructor arguments—which you don't have—to `__new__`. If nobody overrides `__new__` or specifies a `__metaclass__`, they're ignored, so it's not a problem. But if you don't want to support `__new__` or `__metaclass__`, you can use the simpler solution of just setting `__class__`.

Comment: actually, it worked without calling `__init__`: if `x` is an instance of a new-style class `X` with an `__init__` of arity > 0, `x.__class__.__new__(x.__class__)` created an `X` instance without calling the corresponding `__init__`

Comment: @ThiagoSilva: It's not that `__new__` calls `__init__`—it doesn't. It's that `__new__` is documented to get the same arguments as `__init__`, so anyone who's written a `__new__` method will be requiring those arguments, which you don't have. I've explained further in an edit.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your detailed and thorough explanation!